# Изменения модуля корзины Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

В общем мне нужно чтобы цена выводилась из свойства как на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю... Я нашел php файл который отвечает за это все...

```html
        foreach ($arUserColumns as $columnCode => $columnName)
        {
         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_NUMBER")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_NUMBER">
           <div><?=(!CSaleBasketHelper::isSetItem($arItem)) ? $productNumber : ""?></div>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_IMAGE")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_IMAGE">
           <?
           $productImg = "";

           if ($bUseIblock)
           {
            $arProductInfo = $arBasketElement[$arItem["PRODUCT_ID"]];

            if($arProductInfo["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] != "")
             $productImg = $arProductInfo["PREVIEW_PICTURE"];
            elseif($arProductInfo["DETAIL_PICTURE"] != "")
             $productImg = $arProductInfo["DETAIL_PICTURE"];
           }

           if ($productImg != "")
           {
            $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($productImg);
            $productImg = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arFile, array('width'=>80, 'height'=>80), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, false, false);
            $arItem["PICTURE"] = $productImg;
           }

           if (is_array($arItem["PICTURE"]))
             echo '<img src="'.$arItem["PICTURE"]["src"].'" alt="" border="0" />';
            else
             echo '<div class="no_foto">'.GetMessage('SOD_NO_FOTO').'</div>';
           ?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_NAME")
         {
          if ($bUseIblock)
          {
           $arProductInfo = $arBasketElement[$arItem["PRODUCT_ID"]];

           if ($arProductInfo["IBLOCK_ID"] > 0)
           {
            $arItem["EDIT_PAGE_URL"] = CIBlock::GetAdminElementEditLink($arProductInfo["IBLOCK_ID"], $arItem["PRODUCT_ID"], array(
             "find_section_section" => $arProductInfo["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"],
             'WF' => 'Y',
            ));
           }
          }
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_NAME">

           <div class='bx-adm-bigdata-icon-medium-inner' <?=!$arItem['RECOMMENDATION']?'style="visibility: hidden"':''?>></div>

           <?
           $linkClass = (CSaleBasketHelper::isSetItem($arItem)) ? "set-item-link-name" : "";

           if (strlen($arItem["EDIT_PAGE_URL"]) > 0):
           ?>
            <a href="<?echo $arItem["EDIT_PAGE_URL"]?>" class="name-link <?=$linkClass?>" target="_blank">
           <?
           endif;

           echo trim($arItem["NAME"]);

           if (strlen($arItem["EDIT_PAGE_URL"]) > 0):
           ?>
            </a>
           <?
           endif;
           if (CSaleBasketHelper::isSetParent($arItem)):
           ?>
            <div class="set-link-block">
             <a class="dashed-link show-set-link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="set_toggle_link_<?=$arItem["SET_PARENT_ID"]?>" onclick="fToggleSetItems(<?=$arItem["SET_PARENT_ID"]?>);"><?=GetMessage("SOD_SHOW_SET")?></a>
            </div>
           <?
           endif;
           ?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_QUANTITY")
         {
          $measure = (isset($arItem["MEASURE_TEXT"])) ? $arItem["MEASURE_TEXT"] : "";
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_QUANTITY">
           <?echo $arItem["QUANTITY"]."&nbsp".$measure?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_REMAINING_QUANTITY")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_REMAINING_QUANTITY">
           <?
           $balance = 0;
           if ($arItem["MODULE"] == "catalog" && $bUseCatalog)
           {
            $ar_res = CCatalogProduct::GetByID($arItem["PRODUCT_ID"]);
            $balance = FloatVal($ar_res["QUANTITY"]);
           }
           ?>
           <?echo $balance?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_PROPS")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_PROPS">
           <?
           if (!empty($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]]) && is_array($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]]))
           {
            foreach ($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]] as &$val)
            {
             echo htmlspecialcharsex($val["NAME"].": ".$val["VALUE"])."<br />";
            }
            if (isset($val))
             unset($val);
           }
           ?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_PRICE")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_PRICE" nowrap>
            <?
            $priceDiscount = $priceBase = ($arItem["DISCOUNT_PRICE"] + $arItem["PRICE"]);
            if(DoubleVal($priceBase) > 0)
             $priceDiscount = roundEx(($arItem["DISCOUNT_PRICE"] * 100) / $priceBase, SALE_VALUE_PRECISION);
            ?>

            <div class="edit_price">
             <span class="default_price_product" >
              <span class="formated_price"><?=CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat($arItem["PRICE"], $arItem["CURRENCY"], false);?></span>
             </span>
             <span class="currency_price"><?=$CURRENCY_FORMAT?></span>
            </div>
            <?
            if (0 < $priceDiscount)
            {
             ?><div class="base_price" id="DIV_BASE_PRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT_<?=$arItem["PRODUCT_ID"]?>">
              <?=CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat($priceBase, $arItem["CURRENCY"], false);?>
              <span class="currency_price"><?=$CURRENCY_FORMAT?></span>
             </div><?
             if ('Y' != $arItem["CUSTOM_PRICE"])
             {
              ?><div class="discount">(<? echo GetMessage('SOD_PRICE_DISCOUNT')." ".$priceDiscount?>%)</div><?
             }
            }
            ?><div class="base_price_title">
             <?=('Y' == $arItem["CUSTOM_PRICE"]) ? GetMessage("SOD_BASE_CATALOG_PRICE") : $arItem["NOTES"];?>
            </div>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if ($columnCode == "COLUMN_SUM")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="COLUMN_SUM" nowrap>
           <?
           if (!CSaleBasketHelper::isSetItem($arItem)):
           ?>
            <div><?=CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat(($arItem["QUANTITY"] * $arItem["PRICE"]), $arItem["CURRENCY"], false);?> <span><?=$CURRENCY_FORMAT?></span></div>
           <?
           endif;
           ?>
          </td>
          <?
         }

         if (substr($columnCode, 0, 9) == "PROPERTY_")
         {
          ?>
          <td class="property_field <?=$columnCode?>">
           <?=getIblockPropInfo($arBasketPropsValues[$arItem["PRODUCT_ID"]][$columnCode."_VALUE"], $arIblockProps[$columnCode], array("WIDTH" => 90, "HEIGHT" => 90), $ID);?>
          </td>
          <?
         }
        }
        ?>
       </tr>
       <?
       }//end while order
      }
      ?>
      </table>
```

Я беру значение из класса COLUM_PROPS и вот кусок который отвечает за цену в свойстве ".$val["VALUE"]
Я копирую значение VALUE и вставляю вот сюда

```
CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat(($arItem["QUANTITY"] * $arItem["PRICE"]), $arItem["CURRENCY"
```

Вставляю свое значение вот так `CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat(($arItem["QUANTITY"] * $arItem["VALUE"]), $arItem["CURRENCY"` но в заказе все итоговые суммы меняются на 0
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что этот блок со свойствами выводитсяследующим куском кода:

```
<?
if (!empty($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]]) && is_array($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]])) {
  foreach ($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]] as &$val) {
    echo htmlspecialcharsex($val["NAME"].": ".$val["VALUE"])."<br />";
  }
  if (isset($val)) 
    unset($val);
}
?>
```

Сам по себе код неаккуратен и отсюда не очень логичен. Но он дает понять, что интересующаяся вас цена находится вовсе не в массиве **$arItem**, а в **$arBasketProps**. Собственно поэтому ваша попытка обратиться к несуществующему элементу **$arItem["VALUE"]** дает ноль в результате.

Самый простой  способ это поправить, это модицировать вышеуказанный код и лообавить туда сохранение данной цены в отдельную, чтобы в последующем ее использовать при выводе.

Например, так:

```
<?
if (!empty($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]]) && is_array($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]])) {
  $newPrice = 0; //сбрасываем на тот случай, если в свойствах нет нужного поля
  foreach ($arBasketProps[$arItem["ID"]] as &$val) {
    echo htmlspecialcharsex($val["NAME"].": ".$val["VALUE"])."<br />";
    if ($val["NAME"] == "Цена") { //Если имя свойства "Цена"
      $newPrice = $val["VALUE"]; //то сохраняем значение этого свойства в переменную
    }
  }
  if (isset($val)) 
    unset($val);
}
?>
```

А дальше уже выводим:

```
CCurrencyLang::CurrencyFormat(($arItem["QUANTITY"] * $newPrice), $arItem["CURRENCY"
```

Comment: Спасибо, отлично